# Confusing behavior with JavaScript Arguments object

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++){
    var kill = arguments[i];
    arr = arr.filter(function(x){return x != kill;});
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

It removes the elements from an array which equal the optional arguments. This code gives [1,1] as I expect.

But if I change the 4th line to

```
arr = arr.filter(function(x){return x != arguments[i];});
```

I get [1,2,3,1,2,3] instead, when I expect [1,1]. Why is that the case?

Comment: In the second case you use the `arguments` object of the inner function and not the outer one.

Comment: you could use arrow notation `arr = arr.filter(x => x != arguments[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

Because when you use `arguments` within the anonymous function, you're accessing arguments of *that* function, not `destroyer()`.

You will need to copy the `arguments` of `destroyer()`, preferably before your loop as follows:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = arguments;
  
  for(var i=1; i < args.length; i++)
  {
    arr = arr.filter(function(x){return x != args[i];});
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Alternatively, an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) can also be used to achieve the same functionality:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  
  for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++){
     arr = arr.filter(x => x != arguments[i]);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Comment: of course, if you're going to use ES6 ... `function destroyer(arr, ...args) {
    return arr.filter(x => !args.includes(x));
}`